# Could anyone please examplify the garden path model in german?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I want to bring forth some examples of the garden path model in German and am reading the Wikipedia page but get stuck on the examples, for example,

> Welche Politikerin hat die Minister getroffen?

If I am not wrong, it means "Which politician did the ministers meet?". It seems that in English the sentence is alright with no any ambiguity.

Could anyone please explain it a bit to me? Thanks.

---

> A **garden path sentence**, such as “The old man the boat” (meaning “Old people are the crew of the boat”), is a grammatically correct sentence that starts in such a way that a reader’s most likely interpretation will be incorrect; the reader is lured into a parse that turns out to be a dead end or yields a clearly unintended meaning. ([Wikipedia: *Garden path sentence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence))

In German it is called *Holzwegeffekt*, see [Wikipedia: *Holzwegeffekt*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holzwegeffekt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Welche Politikerin hat die Minister getroffen?

Which (female) politician has met the minister**s**?

Consider:

> Welche Politikerin hat **der** Minister getroffen?

Which (female) politician has **been** met **by** the (male) minister?

The "Holzweg" is assuming the (female) politician is the object, because *Welche* is usually introducing an accusative object, not the subject. This is cleared up as soon the article is heard, because its case, number and gender doesn't match that "Holzweg".

Comment: "This is cleared up as soon the article is heard" - not quite; it is only cleared up after hearing that the word after the article is not *Ministerin*.

Comment: When you introduce *Minister**in*** into the sentence, it becomes overall ambigous. One could not tell subject and object apart then and had to guess from context.